# How to print individual array element using Ruby printf() function

Tags: arrays, ruby, printf

I am trying to print out individual elements of a array using printf, this is what I have:

```
printf("\nCard %d: %s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n ", cardNum,card[0],card[1],card[2],card[3])
```

This doesn't really work, well, sort of, it gives me an error like this:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I am really confused on how to do this Ruby, Googled for a while but still couldn't figure out...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `printf` at all. You are calling the `[]` method on the object referenced by the variable `card`, but that object is the `nil` object which doesn't have a `[]` method.

In other words: `cards` isn't an array at all, it is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is the traditional C way of doing this, but there's a shorthand that's more convenient:

```
card = %w[ KD 2C 4D 9S ]
card_num = 1

puts "\nCard %d: %s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n " % [ card_num ] + card
```

But even better:

```
puts "\nCard %d: %s\t%s\n " % [ card_num, card.join("\t") ]
```

The error you're getting relates to `card` being `nil`, which usually means it's undefined.